# Deserialising a DateString

Tags: apex, json, date, deserialize

I do:

```
Date d = (Date)JSON.deserialize('2013-06-07T00:00:00.000Z', Date.class);
System.debug('**********d = ' + d);
```

I expect:

```
*************d = 2013-06-07 00:00:00
```

I see:

```
*************d = 2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems
a. deserializing the date with a time part will throw an exception.  You might want to try deserializing to a Datetime and extract the date from there.

b. Missing quotes.  It should read:

```
Date d = (Date)JSON.deserialize('"2013-06-07"', Date.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using DateTime.valueOf() or DateTime.valueOfGMT() instead of deserializing? They should accept your value as a parameter.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Answer (score 0):

Going by the docs for [Apex JSONParser methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_jsonparser.htm), the following will parse out a DateTime for you:

```
String JSONContent = '{"transactionDate":"2013-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"}';
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(JSONContent);
// Advance to the start object marker.
parser.nextToken();
// Advance to the next value.
parser.nextValue();
// Get the transaction date.
Date transactionDate = parser.getDatetimeValue().date();
System.Debug('Date: ' + transactionDate);
```

Result (based on my timezone):

> USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|Date: 2013-06-06 00:00:00